# Themes doesn't apply on Button's Text

Tags: android, button, themes

I have a theme class "Util" and I have 3 buttons to change the theme in my Activity.
When I apply the theme every **TextView** is working well with themes, **EditText** is not working which made me to change it to TextView and the **Buttons** also don't working.
The thing that i discovered is That the field of text color have to be empty like in TextView.
I Changed my Button to TextView and its worked! But is there any way to make these button work as well??
This is my Util class:

```
    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme){
    sTheme = theme;
    activity.finish();

    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
}

/** Set the theme of the activity, according to the configuration. */
public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity){
    switch (sTheme)
    {
    default:
    case THEME_DEFAULT:
        activity.setTheme(R.style.FirstTheme);
        break;
    case THEME_WHITE:
        activity.setTheme(R.style.SecondTheme);
        break;
    case THEME_BLUE:
        activity.setTheme(R.style.ThirdTheme);
        break;
    }
}

//Shared Preferences
public static int getTheme()
{
    return sTheme;
}

public static boolean canSetThemeFromPrefs( final Activity activity )
{
    boolean result = false;
    SharedPreferences prefMngr = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( activity );
    if ( prefMngr.contains( "Theme_Preferences" ) )
    {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

public static int getThemeFromPrefs( final Activity activity )
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( activity );
    final String themeFromPrefs = preferences.getString( "Theme_Preferences", "THEME_DEFAULT" );
    if ( themeFromPrefs.equals( "THEME_BLUE" ) )
    {
        sTheme = THEME_BLUE;
    }
    else if ( themeFromPrefs.equals( "THEME_WHITE" ) )
    {
        sTheme = THEME_WHITE;
    }
    else
    {
        sTheme = THEME_DEFAULT;
    }

    return getTheme();
}

public static int getThemeFromPrefs( final String key )
{
    if ( key.equals( "THEME_BLUE" ) )
    {
        sTheme = THEME_BLUE;
    }
    else if ( key.equals( "THEME_WHITE" ) )
    {
        sTheme = THEME_WHITE;
    }
    else
    {
        sTheme = THEME_DEFAULT;
    }

    return getTheme();
}
```

Here is my **Button:**

```
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width_numbers"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_width_numbers"
            android:background="@drawable/numbers"
            android:text="@string/button3"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_textsize"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**Update:**

And here is my **Styles.xml**

```
    <!-- Change Layout theme. -->
<!-- Red. -->
<style name="FirstTheme" >
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/first_theme_button</item>
</style>
<!-- Green. Violet -->
<style name="SecondTheme" >
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/second_theme_button</item>
</style>
<!-- Blue. -->
<style name="ThirdTheme" >
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/third_theme_button</item>
</style>
```

And also **Shared Preference** doesn't work and it doesn't save my last Theme!!

Thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible that you don't have styles defined for these elements within your custom themes?

Comment: So why the theme is working with TextView and its not working with Buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this out, and I think I know how to make it work:

```
<style name="SecondTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/SecondTheme</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/SecondTheme</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/second_theme_button</item>
</style>
```

When I did this, I got the edit text and the button in the `second_theme_button` color.

Comment: It is Interesting solution.. it did works fine!! Can you Help me with my second problem?